# How to implement combinations of a list

Tags: kdb

All

I need to get the combinations and permutations of a list.

A function have been implemented for permutations.

```
perm:{[N;l]$[N=1;l;raze .z.s[N-1;l]{x,/:y except x}\:l]}
```

However, I have no idea about combinations, just like this:

```
l: 1 2 3
comb[2;l]
1 2
1 3
2 3

l: 1 2 3 4
comb[3;l]
1 2 3
1 2 4
1 3 4
2 3 4
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

From your solution, you can do:

```
q)comb:{[N;l]$[N=1;l;raze .z.s[N-1;l]{x,/:y where y>max x}\:l]}
q)comb[2;1 2 3]
1 2
1 3
2 3
```

Another approach using `over`:

```
q)perm:{{raze x{x,/:y except x}\:y}[;y]/[x-1;y]}
q)comb:{{raze x{x,/:y where y>max x}\:y}[;y]/[x-1;y]}
```

Comment: Hi Lee,
Thanks for concise code.
It will be great if you could explain the function you have used using over.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use your permutation function like this:

```
q) comb:{[N;l]  distinct asc each  perm[N;l] }

q)l: 1 2 3 4
q) comb[3;l]
```

output:

```
1 2 3

1 2 4

1 3 4

2 3 4
```

**Note:** This will change the order of elements because of `asc`.  So if your list should have `(1 3 2)` in answer, it will give `(1 2 3)`.

To maintain order, use any other function/logic in place of `asc` to filter duplicate elements in sets (ex: `(1 2 3)` and `(1 3 2)` are duplicates).